# Why is my image sequence exporting to a black and white mp4?

Tags: rendering, export, video-sequence-editor, video, color

[image]In order to make mp4 made from an image sequences, I chose:

- ffmpeg video
- container mpeg 4
- video Codec h264
- output Quality: lossless
- encoding speed: slowest

Result: black and white mp4

Blender version: 2.83.4

The source is a video that I convert to images in Blender in order to increase video quality.

When I choose a setting other than lossless, I get the colors in the mp4.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your output settings or include the .blend